# Magento 2: Different servers shows different TTFB for same project

Tags: magento2, optimization

I have the same project copy on two different servers and both the server shows different TTFB.

On one server TTFB is **25ms** & on another server it is **3s**.

Are there any server variables that slow down the TTFB? because of the high TTFB, site is taking long time to load.

Comment: The first course of action should be to make sure that both the servers are idle or have same synthetic load during the testing process.

Answer (score 1):

@fena shah - please check the server configuration and settings as well as the magento settings like cache status and all.

And again you didnt provide more details on server part like what is the config, location and any CDN  / Varnish is in place?

If you provide more details, it will be helpful to evaluate the possible reason behind the problem.